# How do I give a user limited access to theme settings?

Tags: theming, users

I am interested in giving the site administrator some limited access over the appearance. Currently I can give them access to administer themes or not to, and nothing more granular than that. I would like, for instance to limit the themes they can enable and disable to a small number, and perhaps also limit what, within the settings they can change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do that with [hook_menu_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7) to change the access callback on your theme settings page.

e.g,

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu_alter
 */
function mymodule_menu_alter(&$items){
  $items['admin/appearance/settings/my_theme']['access callback'] = 'user_access'; 
  $items['admin/appearance/settings/my_theme']['access arguments'] = array('administer nodes'); 
}
```

You can also add your own access callback and return TRUE or FALSE depending on more custom user access rights access there.

See [system_menu](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.module/function/system_menu/7) for the core `'admin/appearance/settings/' . $theme->name` menu definition